# Camel activemq component - TTL

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want old messages to be automatically removed from topic so I'm using the option `timeToLive` which is described in the [Camel ActiveMQ component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/activemq-component.html). However, it only works with queue and not with topic. Any idea why?

For testing purposes I made this simple route:

```xml
<route>
   <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
   <to uri="activemq:topic:test?timeToLive=10000"/>
</route>
```

Route sends message to my `test` topic with TTL=10seconds. I would expect that after 10 seconds message would disappear.

When I use queue instead everything works as expected ( `<to uri="activemq:queue:test?timeToLive=10000"/>` )

Comment: How do you know the message isn't removed after 10 seconds? How you observe this fact is an important part of the overall use-case.

Comment: I'm using Red Hat Jboss Fuse Management Console to view topic attributes, there I can see that 'Enqueue' on my topic is increasing, but after specified time nothing else happend.. I would expect also increase in 'Dequeue' and 'Expired count' after 10s - as is happening in queue...